# Debug information | Error Stack Trace | Google Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a few endpoints on google cloud. I deployed one more by copying my existing one and changed name and logic.

I was expecting it to be working fine, but while requesting the endpoint I am getting HTTP 500 Status.

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

I tried to look at the logs on cloud endpoint console, but not getting any useful information. Following is what I am getting:

```
{
 insertId:  "***********************11cfe578fa@a1"  
 jsonPayload: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/*********/logs/sample-project-****.appspot.com%2Fendpoints_log"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "********"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 timestamp:  "**********"  
}
```

Is there a way to get the stack trace or more information on what's causing this error?

The rest endpoints are deployed on Google Cloud App Engine and the data is coming from PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please share more information on your environment.

Comment: I have updated my question. Also, can you please tell me what environment information you want? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on GKE, GCE, GAE? If on GAE you need to paste GAE logs, not Endpoints logs.

Comment: It's on GAE but  I can't really see any logs on GAE dashboard.

Comment: I have `logging.warning('Getting Colleges')` in my code. I can't see even these warning messages.

Comment: "Fendpoints_log" in what you've pasted indicates you're searching in wrong logs. As explained in the comment above, GAE logs is what you're interested in, so go to Stackdriver -> Logging and choose "GAE Application" in the first list to choose logs from there. Find the error and by clicking on the duration of the request (which should be in blue) you can choose "View trace" in the pop-up list. That takes you to Stackdriver -> Trace with all the details of the given error.